# Workspace specific wallpapers with Compiz?

Tags: compiz, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace)

Is it possible to get a different wallpaper for each workspace using Compiz? I've found a tutorial telling me to find the Wallpaper option in CompizConfig, but it wasn't there.