# Is there a way to have different wallpaper and different launchers/documents in different workspaces?

Tags: workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workspace specific wallpapers with Compiz?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4497/workspace-specific-wallpapers-with-compiz)

Am running 10.10 and want to have a clean workspace, but also one that might be cluttered (e.g lots of launchers, documents, etc...)... is there a way to do this (am running Compiz)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to have different desktops on different workspaces for a simple reason: there is only one folder ~/Desktop (and no other structure of desktops is currently implemented).

P.S. Even having 4 different backgrounds requires some limitations: you won't be able to see any launchers on the desktop (I currently have this configuration, but I do not use desktop launchers anyway).

There is a standard way of doing this (I guess you know that, but just in case):

- Make sure you have compiz-fusion-plugins-extra and ccsm (CompizConfig) installed
- In CompizConfig find plugin Wallpaper, select wallpapers and check the plugin itself (enable it)
- In the Configuration Editor (gconf-editor) uncheck apps>nautlius>preferences>show desktop

This works for both Compiz Cube and Desktop Wall but in both cases you won't see anything besides different wallpapers (no icons, no launchers, no documents etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see Wallpaper plugin in my CompizConfig so I found a different program that did the trick

[Download Wallpapouz](http://wallpapoz.akbarhome.com/download.html)

Comment: This is why I said make sure you have compiz-plugins-extra installed!