# How to add different wallpapers in different workspaces but as shellscript?

Tags: 10.04, compiz, desktop-background

I want add different wallpapers in different workspaces but as necessary command line ..

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: thank you ..10.04 but script commmand line I necesssary..(as gonftool-2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your environment using the excellent linked Q&A

- Install compiz: `sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`
- Remove your desktop icons: `gconftool-2 --set "/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop" --type=boolean "true"`

Your wallpapers are defined in the key:

```
gconftool-2 --get "/apps/compiz/plugins/wallpaper/screen0/options/bg_image"
```

It takes a comma separated list thus you can set the value using this as an example:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/compiz/plugins/wallpaper/screen0/options/bg_image" --type=string "[/usr/share/backgrounds/BosqueTK.jpg,/usr/share/backgrounds/BusquedaNocturna.jpg]"
```

---

Linked Question:

1. [Workspace specific wallpapers with Compiz?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4497/workspace-specific-wallpapers-with-compiz)