# How to set different wallpaper for each workspaces

Tags: compiz, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workspace specific wallpapers with Compiz?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4497/workspace-specific-wallpapers-with-compiz)
>   [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace)

I am running 12.04 and I can't have set different wallpaper for each workspaces

I've researched it for 2 days and I couldn't even find a post about 12.04 tutorial for

different wallpaper for each workspaces. I tried the ubuntu 11 way but it did not work,

well, it wanted to me to locate to apps/natilus/prefrences and check off the show_desktop

the problem is, I do not have that option. (I have installed compiz manager, compiz plugins extra)

I tried using configuration editor and dconfig-editor well since I heard there's no gconfig-editor for 12.04 ubuntu.

I think I can do it alone if I can finally see that option "show_desktop"

help please !

Comment: @nitstorm its not dup, the previous question is about older version of ubuntu.